Hydrogen and deuterium reaction with neutrons
In my book "Introduction to nuclear engineering" by John R.Lamarsh and Anthony J.Baratta,
(4th edition), they explain
"The nuclei 1H and 2H, which are present in large amounts in many nuclear reactors, interact with neutrons in a somewhat different manner from other nuclei. For one thing, interactions with 1H and 2H do not involve the formation of a compound nucleus. They also do not have any resonances. The cross-section, σs, is constant up to 10KeV, and σγ is l/v at all energies. Furthermore, these nuclei have no excited states (1H is, after all, only a single proton), and so inelastic scattering does not occur."
I can't understand this paragraph.
How does σγ exist if hydrogen and deuterium do not form compound nucleus in the reaction with neutrons?
